# Simplifying a -1 term out of a finite product

Tags: algorithms, summation, products

I've come up with an algorithm that relies upon the value of the following product:

$$Q_{k} =\prod_{n=0}^k [f(n) - 1]$$

Where $f(n) \ge 2$ and strictly increasing integer function [see note]. Importantly, **I already know** the value of $P_{k} = \displaystyle\prod_{n=0..k} f(n)$ from a previous step.

In benchmarking, the $0..k$ loop turns out to be a significant bottleneck in my algorithm, and having to $also$ calculate the $Q_{k}$ product doubles the coefficient so my loop is now $0..2k$ ([big-theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) Θ$(3k)$ if you count the subtraction step).

Hence, **is there any way to simplify the $-1$ term of the above product to avoid looping twice, given I already know $P_{k}$** (as well as $k$, the number of terms)? That is, can I calculate $Q_{k}$ in constant time, given $P_k$ and $k$?

My searching hasn't come up with anything useful, and I'm not even sure it's possible.

---

**N.B.:** I've deliberately avoided a more detailed definition of $f(n)$, because I am curious to know if my question has an answer in the general case, rather than some possible simplification based on the properties of $f(n)$ (which I'm exploring separately). Worse, I actually re-use the same algorithm with multiple $f(n)$s, so defining it here would be pointless.

Comment: Is $f(n)$ guaranteed to be an integer? Or a rational number?

Comment: @StellaBiderman Yes, $f(n)$ is guaranteed to be a positive integer greater than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing the product of all the $f(n)$s here is not going to help you here.

If we multiply out the product of the $(f(n)-1)$s you get something that involves all possible products of *subsets* of the $f(n)$s, with signs depending on the size of each subset. That's not an improvement.

In particular, knowing $P_k$ and $k$ is not enough to know what $Q_k$ is.

As one example, suppose $f(n)=4^{n+1}$. We can move a factor of $2$ from one of the $f(n)$ values to another one without affecting the value of $P_k$, and $f$ will still be strictly increasing. But $Q_k$ will change because
$$(2^{2n}-1)(2^{2m}-1) - (2^{2n-1}-1)(2^{2m+1}-1) = 2^{2m}- 2^{2n-1} $$ which is never zero. And the only way to distinguish between those two cases, starting from the knowledge you have specified, is to inspect all of the $f(n)$s to see if a few of them differ from $4^{n+1}$, which will take linear time no matter how you slice it.

---

(Note, by the way, that $\Theta(3k)$ is the same as $\Theta(k)$ -- the asymptotic notation deliberately ignores constant factors).

Comment: Thanks and +1! As an aside to your aside, sometimes the constant factor matters (i.e., when comparing two algorithms in the same complexity family, which is actually the precise reason I asked this question). When we compare $different$ complexity families, such as linear vs. polynomial, the constants don't matter when k is sufficiently large, but it is only by convention that we usually omit the lower-order terms and coefficients; it's still acceptable to include them when relevant, which is especially useful when comparing two algorithms in the same complexity family.

Comment: @type_outcast: Yes, constant factors may matter -- my point is that the _meaning_ of writing $\Theta$ is to declare that they _don't_ matter to you. You can consider constant factors, you just can't use Landau notation while doing so.

Comment: Landau notation (at least in the few algorithmics texts I could reach without moving my cat) doesn't require (or imply) removal of lower order terms and constant factors. In fact, the formal definition usually goes something like, $f(x) = Θ(g(x)) iff a_1 g(x) \le f(x) \le a_2 g(x)$ for sufficiently large x, which still holds if $g(x)$ is, say, $3k$ instead of $k$. While we do commonly simplify $g(x)$ to ease comparison of different functions, there is certainly no requirement to do so. That said, a lot of different fields use the notation, so it could be different in your area of expertise.

Comment: @type_outcast: Landau notation doesn't _require_ that you omit constant terms, but it does _ignore_ them if you choose to write them: By the definition you quote, $\Theta(3k)$ and $\Theta(k)$ denote the exact same class of functions.

Comment: You've largely re-hashed my first comment, so there really isn't much more I can add, except that I *do* understand your desire for pedantry. You have been far more active on Math SE than I have, so you no doubt have a better grasp on the desired level of formalism in questions asked here. So, by all means, feel free to edit in some more precise notation into my question if you feel sufficiently perturbed by that rogue "3", or anything else for that matter. In any case, my sincere thanks again for answering my math question.